# Retrieve attribute value of link-entity in FetchXML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fetchxml

I have the following code:

```
    Entity account = service.Retrieve("account", ID, new ColumnSet(true));
    string name = (string)account.Attributes["name"];

        const string fetchXmlPattern =
        @"<fetch mapping='logical' version='1.0'>
            <entity name='account'>
                <attribute name='maintname' />
            <filter>
                <condition attribute='maintname' operator='eq' value='{0}' />
            </filter>
            <link-entity name='contact' from='contactid' to='primarycontactid' link-type='inner'>
                <attribute name='accountidname'/>
            </link-entity>
            </entity>
        </fetch>";

        string fetchXml = string.Format(fetchXmlPattern, name);

        var fetchExpression = new FetchExpression(fetchXml);
        EntityCollection response = service.RetrieveMultiple(fetchExpression);
        var records = response.Entities;

        List<Account> Accounts= new List<Account>();

        foreach (var item in records)
        {
            Account AccountFranchisee = new Account();
            AccountFranchisee.ID = (Guid)item.Attributes["accountid"];
            AccountFranchisee.Name = (string)item.Attributes["accountidname"];
            Accounts.Add(AccountFranchisee);
        }
        return Accounts;
```

I get a Key Not Found Exception at this line:

```
AccountFranchisee.Name = (string)item.Attributes["accountidname"];
```

Meaning it can't find the attribute that is in the link-entity. I tried putting aliases, changing pattern, changing syntax, and several solution on the internet, etc... I spent a lot of hours on this thing, still can't figure out what is wrong.

How can I get the value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`accountidname` is an attribute of the linked entity. Therefore you need to use the `Aliased` value to retrieve its value.

First, modify your FetchXml to specify an `alias` for the `link-entity`. Here I've given an alias of "PrimaryContact" - this step isn't really mandatory, but I think it's better to be explicit. If you don't specify an alias, CRM will automatically create one for you (probably "contact1")

```
<fetch mapping='logical' version='1.0'>
  <entity name='account'>
    <attribute name='maintname' />
    <filter>
      <condition attribute='maintname' operator='eq' value='{0}' />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name='contact' from='contactid' to='primarycontactid' link-type='inner' alias='PrimaryContact'>
      <attribute name='accountidname'/>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

Now when you're retrieving the value, you need to combine the alias and the field name
Try something like

```
AccountFranchisee.Name = item.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("PrimaryContact.accountidname").Value;
```

Comment: I sadly can't test this since my traineeship in the company where I developed that came to an end^^ But I did test something similar before writing the issue that I found on another topic. If I remember correctly, I resolved this issue when someone told me like it was perfectly logical that these fetches had to be done on the existing views and not on the actual database tables. Since on views linked entities were already done, no more problems! Still, thank you for your help! :)